# Postgres database query to filter active record result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three tables

1. Company
2. Code
3. CompanyCode [join table] - to store company codes

Now, I want to find records for companies who have code 2,3 and 5 only.

I am trying with

```
Comapny.joins(:codes).where('codes.n_code' IN ? , [2,3,5])
```

but it will result all companies with only `n_code = 2` or `n_code = 3` or `n_code = 5`.

I want companies with `n_code` `2`,`3` and `5` with all these three values.

Comment: I am not familiar with RoR, but in SQL I believe you have to join `codes`  table three times. Please, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @pumbo you are, you can do one join and specify the condition of the codes n_code being 2, 3 or 5.

Comment: @j-dexx give me an example in plain SQL, please

Comment: @pumbo I see what you meant now.  I thought you meant active records `.join` because of rails associations rails is smart enough to automatically to perform the join on company codes and then codes for you.

Comment: you can use `array_agg` to gel a list of codes for every company and then filter for arrays that contain `[2,3,5]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the previous answers is accurate. If you need to get records that have all specified values, but not only some of the values, you don't need to use `WHERE n_code IN (2,3,5)` condition, because it will get all records that have at least one of the values, but not all of them at the same time. Also, additional condition `HAVING count(codes.n_code) = 3`, as suggested earlier, is not a solution, as it does not guarantee that these 3 values are actually 2, 3 and 5.

I am not good at Ruby, so I will give you an example in plain SQL how you can get records that have all of the values:

```
SELECT company_codes.company_id
FROM company_codes
JOIN codes ON codes.id = company_codes.code_id
GROUP BY company_codes.company_id
HAVING array_agg(codes.n_code) @> ARRAY[2, 3, 5]
```

How it works: in `HAVING` section you aggregate all `n_code` values for a company into an array (note that the query is grouped by a company) and check that it contains the array on the right (contains all of its values).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
required_codes = [2, 3, 5]

Company.joins(:codes)
       .where(codes: { n_code: required_codes })
       .group('companies.id')
       .having('count(*) = ?', required_codes.count)
```

Maybe your group clause has to look a bit different depending on your table and field naming.

What it does is:

- Get all companies that have codes
- which contain one of the required codes
- Group them, so that we have for example a group of 3 when the article has the codes 2, 3, 5, or just a group of 2 when the article has the tags 2, 3 and 6.
- Then only take those groups with as many members as specified in our required codes array.

Comment: I want companies that have code [2,3,5] not only 2. Your answer will give me companies with code 2.

Comment: This should not be the case. Did you test the code and read the whole explanation?

Comment: .having('count(*) = ?', required_codes.count) - please explain these. I have read your explanation. but your code doesn't give me any result.

Comment: In your case it means that the group should have the same count as the required_codes array, which is 3.

Comment: Company.joins(:codes)
       .where(codes: { n_code: required_codes }) -> this result 56 companies . but after group by company id with code count = 3 . it results none. But company is available that have 3 codes.

Comment: What does it return if you just do the group without the having?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104395/discussion-between-ingoalbers-and-shefalee-chaudhary).

Comment: It returns same result as Company.joins(:codes) .where(codes: { n_code: required_codes })  this query

Answer (score 0):

Let do the query like this:

```
required_codes = [2, 3, 5]

sub_query = %Q{
  SELECT company_codes.company_id
  FROM company_codes
  JOIN codes
  ON codes.id = company_codes.code_id
  WHERE codes.n_code IN (#{required_codes.join(',')})
  GROUP BY company_codes.company_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT codes.n_code) = #{required_codes.size}
}

Company.where("id IN (#{sub_query})"
```

Explanation:

- The `sub_query` just gets the `company_id` which has all `required_codes` and the distinct codes after grouping must equal the `required_codes`
- After having `company_id`, we can easily query `Company`